# Is The Whitelist Configurable In The MS Anti_XSS Library 3.0?

Tags: xss, antixsslibrary

I've just downloaded and taken a look at the new MS Anti_XSS 3.0 release. I've read through the help file, but I've found no mention of how to modify the whitelist it uses. Can items be added? Can items be removed?

Comment: I would like to know the answer for this too. Did you find anything since you posted this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not, at least not with hacking the code around yourself.

It's in as a feature request though.